# Find APNS Certificate Name with Certificate ID

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to find the certificate name associated with my APNS cert ID , did not find a way on where i can exactly find the same. Need help on this

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but you can find all the information about your account certificates & profiles here : https://developer.apple.com